# how to create Json object of each column in a row

Tags: json, postgresql

i have a table itemmaster in Postgresql.

```
id| attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3
1 | Good       | Average    | Best
```

i want output as json like
[{"attribute1":"Good"},{"attribute2":"Average"},{"attribute3":"Best"}]
i want to use this JSON as nested JSON other object, ihave tried row_to_json and json object builder but not getting exact result.

Comment: This is a strange format, wanting each column as a separate JSON object. The out of the box creation functions do not do that, so you would have to build each column using one of the json object creation methods. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1):

```
select json_build_array(json_build_object('attribute1', itemmaster.attribute1), 
    json_build_object('attribute2', itemmaster.attribute2),
    json_build_object('attribute3', itemmaster.attribute3)) 
from itemmaster;
```

Comment: If I answered the question, then please accept the answer, It tells everyone using stack overflow that the question has been successfully answered

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have table named `table_attr`:

```
id| attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3
1 | Good       | Average    | Best
```

then you can use this query:

```sql
SELECT
    json_agg(t)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            attribute1,
            attribute2,
            attribute3
        FROM
            table_attr
    ) t;
```

output:

> [{"attribute1": "Good", "attribute2": "Average", "attribute3": "Best"}]